# Bootstrap Fixed Top with Div Fixed Above - Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css

I'm having issues with Mozilla and the Position: Fixed CSS attribute.

```
#topDiv {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

[It's a div above the navbar, which is also fixed]

I have tried 100% body which also didnt work.

Edit:

Nothing wrong with the navbar, this is purely a Mozilla Firefox issue as it works perfect for Chrome and IE.

```
nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
```

Comment: and navbar position?

Comment: Your bootstrap navbar probably has a higher z-index. Give `#topDix` a z-index higher than 1030.